# How to continue the outer while loop in a nested if-else condition with PHP?

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a piece of code as following:

```
while ( $conver = mysqli_fetch_assoc($converQ)) // for each conversation
{
    $group_mark = array();

    if ($conver['send_from'] == 1)  // send from group
    {  
        if (in_array($conver['sender_id'], $group_mark)) 
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            array_push($group_mark, $conver['sender_id']);
        }
     ...
```

In the beginning of the `while-loop`, I have to check whether the conversation is from group or individual. If it is from group, I should check whether the `id` has appeared or not. But now the `continue` can not stop executing the following code in the `while-loop` and start the next loop. I think the reason is that its outer function is `if-else` but not the `while-loop` directly. Could you please tell me how to edit the code to do what I want? Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

I have tried this: `continue 2` but it doesn't work. Why?

Thanks to @ThinkingMedia, I know what's the problem now. I put the `$group_mark` in the wrong place. Sorry.

Comment: `continue` does not jump to the outer `if/else`.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia Thanks for you reply! So do you mean my code is right?

Comment: if `in_array($conver['sender_id'], $group_mark)` is true then continue will jump to the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia Thanks a lot. I know what is the problem now.

Answer (score 1):

In these cases which you want to stop check other rows you can develop a function and return as true in the location which you need:

```
function check()
{
    while ( $conver = mysqli_fetch_assoc($converQ)) // for each conversation
    {
     $group_mark = array();

     if ($conver['send_from'] == 1)  // send from group
     {  
         if (in_array($conver['sender_id'], $group_mark)) 
         {
            return true;
         }
         else
         {
             array_push($group_mark, $conver['sender_id']);
         }
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is right. But continue does not jump off those `if/else` statements.

In php [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) they say is deprecated: `continue {var}`

> 5.4.0 Removed the ability to pass in variables (e.g., $num = 2; continue $num;) as the numerical argument.

You can modify your code as follows:

```
while ( $conver = mysqli_fetch_assoc($converQ)) // for each conversation
{
    $group_mark = array();

    if ($conver['send_from'] == 1)  // send from group
    {  
        if (!in_array($conver['sender_id'], $group_mark)) {
            array_push($group_mark, $conver['sender_id']);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found some interesting, curious about why your $group_mark = array(); is in the while loop. It seem like this will get overwrited and will not able to hit the if condition, because of the group_mark always is empty array.

Try to move this to before of your while loop. This should solve and get what you need.

Comment: Yes you are right. The last sentence in my edited question has talked about that.

Comment: Great, I has miss out about new edited description. Good to heard you has solved your problem.